# Django Celery register task from module

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm confused about how can I register only subset of tasks from one django app.
For example we have 2 apps with set of tasks but we need to register 1 app and subset of tasks from second app. How can I achieve that?

Or this can be explained another way. For example we have 2 different projects which are using reusable app with some tasks. And we need to import part of tasks in first project and another part in second. How can we achieve that?

Now I have **celery.autodiscover** but this also importing tasks, which I don't need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in your celery.py file do the configuration like this,

```
from django.conf import settings
app = Celery('redington')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(settings.INSTALLED_APPS, related_name='tasks')
```

in your all apps create file tasks.py file and register your tasks,that will take every app's

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tested it but it should work

> If you disable autodiscover_tasks you can register spesific task with
>   app.register_task(your_task)

from this issue https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4112#issuecomment-313215784